# Spring boot @Valid does not work properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-restcontroller

I'm facing a problem with Spring boot validation. Currently, I'm using Oracle JDK 11.0.12 and Spring boot 2.5.4 to build my project. I added constraints to validate the fields but it does not work. My code here:

```java
import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
public class LoginFormDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotBlank(message = "Login must not be blank")
    private String login;

    @NotNull(message = "Password must be provided")
    private String password;

    private boolean rememberMe = false;
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AccountResource {

    // Logger and autowired components

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<JWTToken> authorize(@Valid @RequestBody LoginFormDTO account) {
        // Some code lines
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new JWTToken(jwt));
    }
}
```

Dependencies in `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
        <version>8.12.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I expect when I send POST request with body

```json
{
  "login": null, // or empty string "", or blank string "    "
  "password": "string",
  "rememberMe": true
}
```

then the server should validate fields then throw exceptions or errors (because of null constraint violation) before executing code in my `authorize(@Valid @RequestBody LoginFormDTO account)` function, but it does not. So what's wrong with spring validation or am I missing something?

Comment: why it does not work. What is the behavior that you get?

Comment: It does not validate the input object. As you can see, login is `null` in input, so the server should validate input then throw `ConstraintViolationException`. But it does not behave like that.

Comment: can you mark class @Validated?

Comment: You mean which one need adding?

Comment: I tried to add it to the rest controller then `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No target Validator set` was thrown. This is not what I'm expecting.

Comment: Have you tried to add BindingResult result. and then use it like this for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) {};

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my `SwaggerConfig` class should use `BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class` instead of `SpringValidatorAdapter.class` in `@Import({})`. Now my validator works normally. Thank João Dias for supporting me in figuring it out.

Comment: If that is the case, don't forget to accept your answer as the correct one so that the question is rendered as "answered" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your `Controller`. You have way too many annotations doing the same thing and even some weird stuff (you return `ResponseEntity` but then you tell Spring that the return of the method should be the Response Body).

This may not fix the `@Valid` issue but for sure will make it simpler:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AccountResource {

    // Logger and autowired components

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public JWTToken authorize(@Valid @RequestBody LoginFormDTO account) {
        // Some code lines
        return new JWTToken(jwt);
    }
}
```

`@RestController` is itself annotated with `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`, which means that `@RequestMapping` methods assume `@ResponseBody` semantics by default, so you don't need to explicitly add it.

Comment: Thank you, it's really simpler and cleaner. But the `@Valid` issue is still unresolved.

Comment: Have you tried adding the getters and setters instead of using Lombok's `@Data`?

Comment: Yah, I tried it, even generated getters, setters my own. It does not work at all.

Comment: I am running out of ideas here. Have you tried `@Validated` instead of `@Valid` as well?

Comment: I tried it too, just like `@Valid`, input went into function without validation.

Comment: Spring Validation is frequently a pain... Do you really need `springfox-bean-validators`? Or can you remove it just for the sake of testing? I am running out of ideas here. Another thing would be the `Serializable`. Do you really need that on your DTO? Finally, I see there a lot of dependencies that seem redundant to me (example: `spring-boot-starter-web` should already include `spring-boot-starter-validation`). Try to clean up a bit your dependencies to narrow down possible sources of issues.

Comment: From Spring boot 2.3, `spring-boot-starter-web` does not include `spring-boot-starter-validation` anymore, maybe you missed this change.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that change. Good to know!